# Python Locating the file path

Tags: python

How to tell python for example, I made a program, which opens a specific .scv

In example `csv=open('c:\Users\Luka\Desktop\prvi.csv','r')`

But when I make an .exe file, that is required to run on all PCs. How can I swap that "Luka" so it works for any PC that has a prvi.csv file on desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os    
os.path.expanduser(path)
```

[Source](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Comment: You should substitute `"~/Desktop/prvi.csv"` for the path to make this answer somewhat more complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
```

1. to get username, use `os.environ['username']`
2. to construct the path to the file, in case file is on desktop on every machine, use

   `csv=open(os.environ['homedrive'] + os.environ['homepath'] + '\\Desktop\\prvi.csv','r')`

Comment: @LukaMihaldinec: The solution by Uku Loskit is not only much simpler: `os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/prvi.csv")`, it also works on Mac OS and on many Linux systems.

Comment: I didn't know ("~/Desktop/prvi.csv") this part :P

Answer (score 0):

check out 
`http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html`

Should be

```
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
```

Store the username in a variable and substitute in your path name.